# JavaFX Determine Window State (Maximized, Minimized, or Normal)

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to detect the window state of a JavaFX application.  I am struggling with the following use-case:

> 1. Maximize the application (sets the maximized property to true)
> 2. Minimize the application (sets the iconified property to true)
> 3. Switch between minimized and maximized any number of times

After following the above steps, the window is either maximized or minimized.  However, both the `maximized` and `iconified` properties are set to true.  How can I determine which of the two states the window is in?  The best I could come up with was the following:

```
static WindowState getState(final Stage window) {
    WindowState result;
    final boolean isMaximized = window.isMaximized();
    final boolean isMinimized = window.isIconified();
    if (isMaximized && isMinimized) {
        // JavaFX is odd in that it allows this state.
        // What is the best way to determine which state it is really in?
        // Best I could come up with is:
        result = (window.getX() <= -32000 ? Minimized : Maximized);
    } else if (isMaximized) {
        result = Maximized;
    } else if (isMinimized) {
        result = Minimized;
    } else {
        result = Normal;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The reason that I need to be able to determine this is I am trying to track the location and state of the window, so I can save it to a preferences file.  Is there a better way than comparing the window location to -32000 to determine which state the window is actually in when both `isMaximized` and `isIconified` are true?  I am using JDK 8u74, and observe this behavior in Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64.

Comment: window.WindowState should give you Max or Min I'm not at my computer so I can't test it but WindowState is a property of Stage

Comment: @PhilipVaughn Thank you for the suggestion.  I searched through the [Java SE8 Stage Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) for the words *window* and *state*, but couldn't come up with anything.  However, it is possible that either 1) I overlooked it during the search, or 2) it is available as a property, but with a different name.

Comment: just a thought: what does maximized mean? on Mac OSX for example, maximized could mean that the window including window decorations like title bar, close buttons etc ist maximized, but all these elements are still visible and so is the menu bar. Same for Win, where there is the taskbar with the start menu at the bottom. But there also is the fullscreen-mode, where all those elements are hidden and only the inner viewport of the application covers the whole screen area.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I would define "maximized" to be a state such that the window decorations (e.g., title bar, min/max/close buttons) are visible.  JavaFX has another feature, the [fullScreen property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#fullScreenProperty), which enables maximization without decorations.  In my particular use-case, the `fullScreen` property is false.